# Creating a mysql function that will produce a string indicating the size of a book

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a function that will produce a string indicating the size of a book, but it is not working. Any suggestions?

```
delimiter  # 
Drop function if exists a_testbed.BookSize #  
Create function a_testbed.BookSize(book int)  
Returns varchar(10) 
Begin 
Declare v_pages int;
Declare in_book varchar(10);   
    if(v_pages <= 200) then      
      Set in_book = 'mini';    
    elseif(v_pages <= 500) then
      Set in_book = 'small';
    elseif(v_pages <= 1500) then
      Set in_book = 'medium'; 
    elseif(v_pages > 1500) then
      Set in_book = 'large';
    else
      Set in_book ='Invalid Input';
    end if;   
 Return in_book ;
end; #
```

Trying to produce output as a sample:

```
select a_testbed.BookSize(200)#
```

Comment: What does “not working” mean? It throws an error? What is the error message? It didn’t do what you expected? What did it do? What did you expect? Why do you think the two are different?

Comment: select a_testbed.BookSize(200)# produces an error 1406 Data too long for column in_book at row '1'

Comment: However my function is not correct and I am trying to figure out why?

Comment: @user2966637 See, that's why you put the error message in the question. You've defined `in_book` as `varchar(10)` but try to set it to `Invalid Input`, which is 13 characters.

Comment: Please stop adding random tags to your questions. If your question is about MySQL, what does it have to do with functional or procedural programming? Please read the descriptions of the tags before you add them to your questions. Picking random ones help no one, including you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well first off, in your final `else` conditional, you set the return value to a value more than 10 characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create function BookSize(book int)  
Returns varchar(10) 
Begin 
Declare in_book varchar(10);   
    if(book <= 200) then      
      Set in_book = 'mini';    
    elseif(book <= 500) then
      Set in_book = 'small';
    elseif(book <= 1500) then
      Set in_book = 'medium'; 
    elseif(book > 1500) then
      Set in_book = 'large';
    else
      Set in_book ='Invalid';
    end if;   
 Return in_book ;
END
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a0ed/1/0) here, I did it because i was curious on how to create a function :)